# Bindable Entry is not working inside custom control in Xamarin.forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an entry field  inside custom control. I've created bindable property for the same.

Here's my code :

```
public string MyEntry
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(MyEntryProperty);
        set => SetValue(MyEntryProperty, value);
    }
    public static BindableProperty MyEntryProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
                                             propertyName: "MyEntry",
                                             returnType: typeof(string),
                                             declaringType: typeof(MyView),
                                             defaultValue: string.Empty,
                                             defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
                                             propertyChanged:MyEntryPropertyChanged );


 public static void MyEntryPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
       var cView = (MyView)bindable;
       cView.myent.Text = (string)newValue;
   }
```

Then on my  actual view xaml :

<MyView MyEntry={Binding Something}/>

But it's not working.? Any suggestions?

Comment: The property is not Text, but called `MyEntryProperty`. This would be the proper binding `<MyEntry MyEntry={Binding Something}/>`... But I'm not sure if its possible to have the declaring type and the property having the same name.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? it seems like you just need to use an ```Entry``` and have no use for a custom entry.

Comment: Updated the xaml. Basically custom control has entry field and i'm trying to capture entry field text by bindable property but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you do not set the binding correctly. I make a code sample for your reference.

MyView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView
x:Class="XamarinDemo.Custom_Control.MyView"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<StackLayout>
    <Entry
        x:Name="myent"
        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
        Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    <Button />
</StackLayout>

</ContentView>
```

Code Behind: Same with yours.

```
 public partial class MyView : ContentView
{
    public MyView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public string MyEntry
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(MyEntryProperty);
        set => SetValue(MyEntryProperty, value);
    }
    public static BindableProperty MyEntryProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
                                             propertyName: "MyEntry",
                                             returnType: typeof(string),
                                             declaringType: typeof(MyView),
                                             defaultValue: string.Empty,
                                             defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
                                             propertyChanged: MyEntryPropertyChanged);


    public static void MyEntryPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var cView = (MyView)bindable;
        cView.myent.Text = (string)newValue;
    }
}
```

**Usage: Page1.xaml**

```
 <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <local:MyView MyEntry="{Binding Something}"></local:MyView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

**Binding:**

```
 public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
{
    public string Something { get; set; }
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Something = "Hello";
        this.BindingContext = this;
    }
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Since its entry field i want user to input the text and that's where it always appears as empty.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue with a custom control of mine, the main problem was my binding context was not set correctly.

The way that I used to check this was

1. I gave my control a `x:name` in the xaml
2. I went to the pagename.cs (code behind) in the constructor after the `InializeComponents()` method I typed this

```
Console.WriteLine($"Control-{ControlXname.BindingContext();}");
Console.WriteLine($"Page-{this.BindingContext();}");
```

3. After i excuted my code i headed to the output panel and i pressed ctrl + f to search for the word "Control-" and "Page-" only then i have found out that thier binding contexts was different.

Answer (score 0):

You are only setting value to Entry, you are not reading back the changes from Entry. You have to add following in your constructor.

```
// ... add this in your constructor...
myent.SetBinding(Entry.TextProperty, new Binding{
    Path = "MyEntry",
    Source = this,
    Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
});



public string MyEntry
{
    get => (string)GetValue(MyEntryProperty);
    set => SetValue(MyEntryProperty, value);
}

// remove onPropertyChanged
public static BindableProperty MyEntryProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
                                         propertyName: "MyEntry",
                                         returnType: typeof(string),
                                         declaringType: typeof(MyView),
                                         defaultValue: string.Empty,
                                         defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);
```